# Discord Bot is not playing mp3 file before leaving

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently writing a discord bot, which should execute the mp3 file with the command “!leave” and then leave the channel. Unfortunately, the bot leaves either the channel and does not play the mp3 file or (without await command) the bot plays the mp3 file, but does not leave the channel

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client:
        voice = ctx.channel.guild.voice_client
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(r"C:\Users\***\Desktop\DiscordBot\bye.mp3"))
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("test ")
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me. I did not find any solutions via google etc.

Best regards
Traffix

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, [VoiceClient.play](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=play#discord.VoiceClient.play) will not wait for the source to finish before continuing your code. Try using the `after` parameter of `voice.play` instead:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client:
        voice = ctx.channel.guild.voice_client

        async def leave_vc(exc):
            if exc:
                print("Something went wrong!", exc)
            await voice.disconnect()

        voice.play(
            discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(r"C:\Users\***\Desktop\DiscordBot\bye.mp3"),
            after=lambda exc: ctx.bot.loop.run_until_complete(leave_vc(exc))
        )
    else:
        await ctx.send("test ")
```

I don't have a way to test this, so I can't guarantee that it will work right away.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Unfortunately it isnt working yet. The audio is playing but after that an error is shown : "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'VoiceClient.disconnect' was never awaited
  traceback.print_exception(type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

Comment: @Traffix Did it leave the voice channel, even though an error occurred?

Comment: @Traffix try using `asyncio.run(voice.disconnect())` instead of `ctx.bot.loop.run_until_complete(voice.disconnect())`. You'll have to `import asyncio` too.

Comment: Still the same (audio plays but no disconnect) with different error. Error: "RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-31' coro=<VoiceClient.disconnect() running at C:...."

Comment: @Traffix I edited it one last time, if this doesn't work then I don't know what will.

Comment: still not working :( only the audio. But I appreciate your help. If I get a solution, I will let you know! Thx

Comment: got a solution, not the best, but a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Don't think thats a great solution but it is working ^^ if anyone has a better solution pls let me know :)

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client:
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client
        
        voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(r"C:\Users\***\Desktop\DiscordBot\bye.mp3"))
        counter = 0
        duration = 3

        while not counter >= duration:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            counter = counter + 1
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("test ")
```